# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop Error in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, key, react-native-flatlist

hey guys iam building a list  in an app with react-native  iam following a video and my code is exactly like him but for some reason i still get an error that tell me each child in the list need a key even tho iam providing one.

```
 function addGoalHandler() {
    setCourseGoals(currentCourseGoals => [...currentCourseGoals,
       {text:enteredGoalText,key: Math.random().toString()}]);
  };

<FlatList 
        data={courseGoals}
         renderItem={(itemData) => 
          { 
            return <Goalitem text={itemData.item.text}/>;
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) =>
          {
            return item.id;
          }} />
```

this is the code that matter for the key and the list
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at CellRenderer (http://192.168.1.13:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:58327:36)
    in VirtualizedList (created by FlatList)
    in FlatList (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

this the error that iam getting
i tried to find a solution but i couldnt so i would appreciate some help < 3

i trid to go the docs or search here for a solution but i foudn nothing that helped me

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Math.random()` for the key. If there's really nothing else to distinguish between the items other than the position, then just `return index`.

Comment: Also, while warnings are useful and important, they are not errors. Your app will work with warning although may break in unexpected ways. If your app doesn't render that means there's another issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

First of all you're using the `id` and the `item` doesn't have an `id` it has an `key`, In the second part you shouldn't use `Math.Random`

**Solution:**

to solve the issue just use the `key` and the `index` together like this:

```
<FlatList 
        data={courseGoals}
         renderItem={(itemData) => 
          { 
            return <Goalitem text={itemData.item.text}/>;
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) =>
          {
            return `${item.key}-${index.toString()}`;
          }} />
```

Hope it helps you :D